# Notificaciones push en Android

Tags: android-studio, pusher

Tengo un sistema web (.NET MVC) para la empresa donde trabajo, en la cual el usuario hace algunas operaciones CRUD. Entonces realicé una app en Android Studio la cual muestra un recyclerview de los registros que los usuarios Crean en el sistema web que mencioné al inicio, para esto creé un servidor .NET MVC también. Pero lo que necesito es que cada que se haga un insert (a la base de datos) en el sistema web, llegue una notificación a la app móvil.

Estuve leyendo sobre PUSHER, me registré y me dió el siguiente código:

Cliente Android

```html
PusherOptions options = new PusherOptions();
        options.setCluster("xxx");
        Pusher pusher = new Pusher("xxx", options);

        pusher.connect(new ConnectionEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConnectionStateChange(ConnectionStateChange change) {
                System.out.println("Estado cambio de " + change.getPreviousState() + " a " + change.getCurrentState());
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String message, String code, Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error de conexión! " +
                        "\ncode: " + code +
                        "\nmessage: " + message +
                        "\nException: " + e
                );
            }
        }, ConnectionState.ALL);

        Channel channel = pusher.subscribe("my-channel");

        channel.bind("my-event", new SubscriptionEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(PusherEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Received event with data: " + event.toString());
            }
        });
```

Y para el servidor .NET MVC

```html
     public class HelloWorldController : Controller
     {
            [HttpPost]
            public async Task<ActionResult> Notificaciones()
            {
                var options = new PusherOptions
                {
                    Cluster = "xxx",
                    Encrypted = true
                };

                var pusher = new Pusher(
                  "xxx",
                  "xxxx",
                  "xxxx",
                  options);

                var result = await pusher.TriggerAsync(
                  "my-channel",
                  "my-event",
                  new { message = "hello world" });

            return new HttpStatusCodeResult((int)HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
        }
```

La verdad estoy muy perdido y no se como usarlo, leí la documentación pero lo usan con firebase, pero yo debo usar las bases que tienen en un servidor privado de mi empresa. Si alguien puede guiarme o decirme sobre alguna otra manera de hacer lo que necesito.
Gracias

Comment: Hola! Alguno de los System.out.println() se ejecutan luego de mandar un push notification desde tu server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que podrías hacer en este caso es utilizar [Cloud Messaging (FCM)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/?hl=es-419&gclid=Cj0KCQjwka_1BRCPARIsAMlUmEqdpHvyMUxDRlbzSjJ4TGuXWFXP3-sSldTKxdVbD5MpTH6K0LYV8c0aAhOTEALw_wcB) de Firebase que no tiene [costo](https://firebase.google.com/pricing?hl=es-419) (sin cargo). Para esto necesitas [agregar Firebase a tu proyecto de Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup?hl=es-419).

Para agregar Firebase a tu proyecto debes:

- Crear un proyecto en Firebase
- Registrar tu app con Firebase dando clic en el ícono de **Android** en la página de tu proyecto en Firebase, para iniciar el flujo de configuración.
- Agregar el archivo de Firebase a tu aplicación, pegando el archivo `google-services.json` en Android Studio en la carpeta raíz de tu proyecto.
- Agrega los SDK de Firebase a tu aplicación agregando la dependencia en `app/build.gradle` de tu módulo (nivel de app).

> Para utilizar FCM de Firebase, no necesariamente debes utilizar la
>   base de datos de Firebase, puedes utilizar tu propia base de datos
>   privada.

Para enviar la notificación a los dispositivos móviles mediante el servicio FCM puedes utilizar el [SDK de Firebase Admin](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message?hl=es#c) que esta disponible para el lenguaje C#, mediante este SDK puedes notificar a los dispositivos móviles cuando realices un nuevo insert.

Este es un ejemplo del lo que podría ir en tu servidor `.NET MVC` para enviar una notificación a un dispositivo:

```cs
// Este token de registro viene del cliente de FCM, es decir del
// dispositivo Android.
var registrationToken = "TU_TOKEN_DE_REGISTRO";

// Creación y cuerpo del mensaje.
var message = new Message()
{
    Data = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "puntaje", "850" },
        { "hora", "2:45" },
    },
    Token = registrationToken,
};

// Enviar el mensaje al dispositivo al que le pertenece
// el token de registro
string response = await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync(message);
// La respuesta es un ID como cadena de texto.
Console.WriteLine("Mensaje enviado con éxito: " + response);
```

Hay que tener en cuenta lo que menciona @Juan que cada vez que se instala una aplicación en Android se crea un token de Firebase por dispositivo ese token hay que almacenarlo y monitorear que este activo, ya que por ejemplo si una persona desinstala la aplicación y la vuelve a instalar el token cambia. Además hay que tener en cuenta el concepto de [temas](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging?hl=es-419) que maneja Firebase para mandar notificaciones a varios dispositivos, [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38237559/how-do-you-send-a-firebase-notification-to-all-devices-via-curl) está un ejemplo como enviar un mensaje a todos los dispositivos en el caso que lo necesites o puedes enviar notificaciones a dispositivos específicos mediante su token como en el código de ejemplo.

Comment: Esto como se podría implementar usando Android Studio, podrías agregar un ejemplo?, considera revisar [answer], saludos.

Comment: En Android Studio lo que iría es la configuración para agregar Firebase al proyecto y el código para enviar el token al servidor para almacenarlo (aquí también podría ir la subscripción a un topic) y poder enviar una notificación desde el servidor.

Answer (score 1):

Voy a considerar "Estoy muy perdido" como la pregunta, por lo que esta respuesta es para orientarte.

Por lo que leí en la documentación de Pusher, sigue el patrón de canales o channels de tipo publish-subscribe, donde un cliente se suscribe a un a channel y un servidor envía mensajes al canal y todos los subscriptos al canal reciben el mensaje.

Por otro lado tenés canales publicos, privados, y de presencia. Los dos últimos necesitan que el cliente se autentique.

Entendería que para una aplicación corporativa estarías necesitando usar canales privados. Si el insert en la base de datos es para ser notificado a un usuario en particular, que depende del registro insertado, entonces necestias un canal por usuario, por otro lados si los inserts en la base de datos son para ser comunicados a todos los usuarios, podrias usar un solo canal para todos los usuarios.

En cuanto al lado del serividor, me parece que la integración no es a nivel de base de datos sino a nivel de la aplicación que hace el insert.
Necesitas agregar a las dependencias del proyecto de esa aplicación las librerias de Pusher (librerias de servidor). Y cuando la aplicación hace un insert en la base de datos, luego de comitearla, puede publicar el evento en el canal correspondiente.

No está escrito expresamente pero me parece que algo de administración para Pusher vas a tener que armar del lado del servidor en la base de datos, por lo menos para la autenticación del usuario y si hay canales individuales, también llevar que canal es para que usuario, quizás algunas cosas más.

La documentación de la página está bastante bien. Por ahí necesitas armar un modelo simple para entender como funcionan las partes antes de ir a implementar el proyecto completo.

Respecto a otras formas de hacerlo:

Hay muchos proveedores que por atrás usan Firebase (One Signal, Urban Airship, etc). Fijate las condiciones de uso antes de decidirte por alguna (también revisá las condiciones de uso de Pusher).

Las basadas en Firebase usan el concepto de "topic" para que un cliente pueda recibir notificaciones similar al canal de Pusher.

Pero a diferencia de Pusher, las notificaciones individuales no se envian a "topics" sino que se envían a un "token" o aun grupo de "tokens".

El "token" es un identificador del dispositivo generado por Firebase, y el mismo puede cambiar en cualquier momento.

Por este motivo, para mensajes individuales, necestias por un lado llevar en el server la administración de los tokens de los usuarios para saber cual está vigente para cada uno. Por otro lado necestas código en la app para enviar el "token" al server para ser refrescado cuando Firebase decida generar un token nuevo para el dispositivo.

Y también algo de manejo de erres cuando mandas las notificaciones dado que un "token" que parece vigente, puede no estarlo.